# Scaling output from stable output

Tags: tables, longtable, xtable, scalebox

```
print(xtable(x, type = "latex"),
  floating = FALSE,
  tabular.environment = "longtable",
  file = "/Path/Filename.tex")
```

I am using the above code to output a table directly from R.  I am using longtable because I need it to span pages.  But I also need to scale it, so it fits on each page.

I thought it would be as simple as:

```
print(xtable(x, type = "latex"),
  floating = FALSE,
  tabular.environment = "longtable",
  scalebox = 0.7,
  file = "/Users/burtonpp/Documents/Tex/InfoTrellis/tables/pipeline.tex")
```

But, alas, this does not work.  The scalebox line causes it not to compile.

Thoughts?

Comment: I fairly sure that a `scalebox` cannot span pages, so putting a `longtable` inside a `scalebox` cannot work. You need to do something else, like reducing font size or if there is a lot of text in one of the columns, make it a `p` column or similar, so the text will wrap across lines.

Comment: You should never use `\scalebox` for tables. You'll get inconsistent font sizes and sometimes unreadable tables. It's bettr to play with the font size locally, and/or the value of `\tabcolsep` (default  6pt).

Comment: scaling tables is simply evil, why would you do that?:-)  (scalebox can not be broken over a page, longtable can do nothing inside such a box)

Answer (score 1):

```
p <- xtable(x)
align(p) <- "lp{0.5in}p{1.5in}p{1.5in}p{1in}p{1in}"

print(p, 
  tabular.environment = "longtable", 
  floating = FALSE, 
  file = "/path/file.tex")
```

This works.